# Creating Mongoose Model takes indefinite amount of time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I tried creating a simple Mongoose schema, and then a corresponding route to handle saving of restaurant models.

//models/Restaurant.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
});

export default mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);
```

// routes/restaurants.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Restaurant = require('../models/Restaurant')

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, description } = req.body
        let restaurant = new Restaurant({name, description}) 
console.log(restaurant)
// does not print anything to the console and the program stops here for an indefinite amount of time.
        restaurant = await restaurant.save()
        res.status(200)
        res.json(restaurant)


    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500)
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

Why does the program stop at creating restaurants for an indefinite amount of time? Is there something wrong with the way I setup my mongoose schemas/model/or the way I create a new model?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you confuse ES6 and CommonJS modules.

Don't confuse ES6 and CommonJS. Choose one or the other. In this code sample, I'll revise your model with CommonJS style of writing. Node.js uses CommonJS by default, but I believe it can be changed.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
});

const Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', restaurantSchema);

module.exports = Restaurant;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I left out `save` because the problem in the first place is that the program runs indefinitely after the `new Restaurant` line.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with me mixing ES6 with common JS! How I exported the Restaurant model was incompatible with the way I imported it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you edit your answer such that the correct solution is on top?

Answer (score 0):

before console.log() you need to call save method

```
let restaurant = new Restaurant({name, description});
restaurant = await restaurant.save();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I left out `save` because the problem in the first place is that the program runs indefinitely after the `new Restaurant` line.